# iOS photo upload to azure fails

Tags: ios, image, azure, azure-storage

I started to study windows azure cloud and how to use it with iOS. My goal is to create an application that uploads a picture taken with iPhones camera and store it to azure.

I opened an azure account to www.windowsazure.com/ and followed the instructions in the page to create a mobile service. Then I downloaded the quickstart xcode project which is automatically connected to my newly created mobile service.

Text upload works like a charm I was able to store text to the mobile service using the quickstart app. The problems started when I wanted to store an image taken with the iPhones camera.

I created another view to quickstart project where I can launch the camera and when picture is taken it is stored to UIImageView. Then when I click the publish button I run this code:

```
- (IBAction)PublishButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    NSString *imageData = nil;
    if (self.PhotoImageView.image != nil) {
        NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.PhotoImageView.image);
        [Base64 initialize];
        imageData = [Base64 encode:data];

    }
    int tmp = imageData.length;

    NSDictionary *item = @{ @"text" : self.ImageTextField.text, @"complete" : @(NO), @"imageString":imageData };
    [self.todoService addItem:item completion:^(NSUInteger index){
        UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Photo uploaded successfully" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }];
}
```

I am able to upload a small PNG and JPG file, less than 6KB but I think the camera image is too big for my database? Or is it just too big to be sent with phones connection? How can I make it smaller?

I am using the TodoService to upload the data to the server.

Comment: Is `the TodoService` something I should know what it is? EDIT: Ah, something from the Azure samples.

Comment: Yes, it is the class azure tools generate to handle the item uploading to the mobile service.

Comment: I don't believe the column storing your image data which will be a varchar on the SQL database side is limited in size (but I may be wrong).  Also, the recommended approach is to not store the binary (in this case string) data in your Mobile Service DB but to instead use blob storage per this walkthrough (http://www.nickharris.net/2012/09/windows-8-how-to-upload-an-image-using-a-blob-storage-sas-generated-by-windows-azure-mobile-services/ - this is a Windows Store sample but the methodology is the same, you'd just need to account for client differences).

Comment: I was actually able to store also the picture data when I used UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.PhotoImageView.image, 0.3f); to jpg encoding. When the size is smaller the image could be stored. But I also started to think that this might not be the right place to store it. Thanks for the link, I have to learn more about the blob storage!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use Blob Storage rather than a SQL db.  I'd recommend using the SQL db either as a 'dummy' or to hold other information like use profile details. You can access Blob Storage through scripts in the 'Data' tab.

Comment: Thanks Mlunes for the answer. Is there any tutorials on how to write scripts in the 'Data' tab?

Comment: I think I found what I was looking for behind the link Chris posted up above: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/resources-ios/

Comment: Sure thing--here's the working with data in scripts tutorial: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/validate-modify-and-augment-data-ios/  I'd also recommend taking a look through this collection of helpful links: aka.ms/CommonWAMS

Comment: So the right way to use blob storage with iOS is to use it via the scipts in the data page? I wasn't even sure about that and I have been checking if I could find an API for that or something else..

Comment: I am starting to think that I really need some API for iOS.

I checked this tutorial: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Upload-File-to-Windows-c9169190

It is for MS but the serverside scripting is the same for all the clients. I think until step 7 it is pretty straight forward but what do you have to do after that? In WP8 there is the storage client library but is there something similar for iOS?

Comment: Check out Josh's post here: http://thejoyofcode.com/Using_the_scheduler_to_backup_your_Mobile_Service_database.aspx, which includes some information for using Blob Storage with iOS.

Comment: If you have more detailed questions, might be easier to shoot an email to ios (at) microsoft (dot) com.